# How to list chapter titles from a YouTube video using youtube-dl / yt-dlp

Tags: youtube-dl

Some YouTube content creators split their videos into chapters. A subset of them kindly offer the list of chapters titles on description video, with their starting timestamp. Sometimes they decide not to show them.

How can I get the list of chapters titles?

Comment: "Some YouTube content creators split their videos into chapters." Note that sometimes chapters are generated automatically by YouTube: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9884579?hl=en

Answer (score 7):

One-liner to do this using [`yt-dlp`](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) (better alternative to [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl)) and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON processor:

```bash
yt-dlp --dump-json  videoIDorURL | jq --raw-output ".chapters[].title"
```

To get starting timestamps:

```bash
 | jq --raw-output ".chapters[].start_time" | awk '{printf("%d:%02d:%02d\n",($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60),($1%60))}'
```

With [`paste`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html) and [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution)
you can combine both. This is a function you could add to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`:

```bash
function get_chapters_times() {
  paste <(yt-dlp --dump-json $1 | jq --raw-output ".chapters[].start_time" | awk '{printf("%d:%02d:%02d\n",($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60),($1%60))}') <(yt-dlp --dump-json $1 | jq --raw-output ".chapters[].title")
}
```

Will return:

```
$ get_chapters_times https://youtu.be/DxL2HoqLbyA
0:00:00 Intro
0:02:15 History
0:04:16 Ideal Engine
0:09:48 Entropy
0:11:03 Energy Spread
0:14:49 Air Conditioning
0:17:26 Life on Earth
0:19:35 The Past Hypothesis
0:21:43 Hawking Radiation
0:23:31 Heat Death of the Universe
0:24:52 Conclusion
```

Use [`yt-dlp --split-chapters`](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) to download each chapter.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a fancier one-liner inspired by Pablo's answer that does away with process substitution and having to define functions:
`yt-dlp videoURL --dump-json | jq -r ".chapters[] | {start_time, title}" | awk -v count="2" '++count==4{$0=sprintf("  \"start\":%d:%02d:%02d",($2/60/60%24),($2/60%60),($2%60));count=0} 1' | awk -F '":' '{print $2}' | gsed -r -e '/^\s*$/d' -e 's/^ "|"$//g' | paste -d " "  - -`
The awks and gsed could probably be merged into each other at the cost of more complexity.

If using `yt-dlp`, you may also benefit from `--embed-chapters` (alias:
`--add-chapters`) argument.